# javascript Assign the array inside variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to assign a array inside a variable in javascript. But i am getting error like this. Could you please correct me where i have missed.

"TypeError: newItems.json is undefined"

```
var newItems = [];
if ($$('.selectvals:checked').length > 0) {
     var i=0;
     $$('.selectvals:checked').each(function (e) {
        var row = e.parentNode.parentNode;
        var jsonVals = row.down('.jsonval').value;
        var jsonPaymentVals = row.down('amount').value;
        newItems['json'][i] = jsonVals;
        newItems['amount'][i] = jsonPaymentVals;
        i++;
     });
}
```

Comment: that you try to change the property `[i]` of an object that doesn't exist `newItems['json']`

Comment: Because `newItems` is an array and not an object. You should be using `var newItems = {}`.

Comment: @ Terry I am getting the same error even I delcared like this var newItems = {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need initialize right it, like this:

```
var newItems = {
   json:[],
   amount:[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. when i checked the console. it's going like this in the post method.. from 

postvals[] : [object Object]